# How to validate all screens in view pager at last page for all screens edittext?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to set validation to the last screen that all swiped screens data will be inserted by the user or not using viewpager.

pageradapter class

```
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;
    private int[] layouts;

    public MyViewPagerAdapter(Context context,int[] layouts) {
        this.context=context;
        this.layouts=layouts;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return layouts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return view == obj;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View view = (View) object;
        container.removeView(view);
    }
```

adding layouts to viewpager in activities oncreate method

```
layouts = new int[]{
                R.layout.welcome_side1,
                R.layout.welcome_side2,
                R.layout.welcome_side3,
                R.layout.welcome_side4};

        // making notification bar transparent
        changeStatusBarColor();

        myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(context,layouts);
        viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);
```

button click in activity i want to validate here about my first screen edittext

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int current = getItem(+1);
                if (current < layouts.length) {
                    // move to next screen
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
                } else {
                    //i want to validate here about my all layout files empty fields or user insert correct valuers.
                }
            }
        });
```

my all layout screens are like that I want to validate edit text has value or not and jump to particular screens using page adapter.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_screen1">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearlayout1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it like this

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int current = getItem(+1);
            if (current < layouts.length) {
                // move to next screen
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < viewPager.getChildCount(); i++) {
                   View v = viewPager.getChildAt(i);
                   EditText ed = v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                   if (ed != null) {
                       if (ed.getText() == null || ed.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                             // here text is empty, do something...
                           return;
                       }
                    }
                }
                // here, all edittext were edited, do something
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: See my edited answer. Just test if `getText()`is null

Comment: when i go to particular page using viewPager.setCurrentItem(0); but it will vanish other data how to get inserted data back to particular page

Comment: You mean that when you change your current page, values from other (or some) pages are lost? If yes, this is because pages are being recreated. So, you should save `editText` values somewhere before changing a page. Then, get these values in `instantiateItem` function.

Comment: It is a little complicated to explain this in a comment. It's better to use an array of `class`instead of an array of `int`. This class can have 2 variables, the layout id and a string. Then, in the `onClick`event you can save the `editText` value into the string before changing the page. In the `instantiateItem` you can reset the edittext with this saved string. If it's not clear enough, better put another question to be able to write it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Use MVP pattern or at least make Presenter part/something for data storing (separate for each fragment), and then get your data from them later. If you are not sure, how to do that then ask yourself how are you handling screen orientation (maybe you already have something for that, so try to use it)(not saying about onSaveInstanceState()).